# Array destructuring and spread operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

It's not 100% clear to me how this piece of code works:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];

[x, y, ...a ] = [0, ...a, 4];

// OUTPUT:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I'm deconstructing the array `a` using the `...` operator.

I am expecting that in second line a bunch of assignments will take place.

The `x` will be assigned to 0, `y` will be assigned to `...a` (which passes the elements in the array `a` as individual values).

It's not clear to me, though, how the `...a` get assigned to 4. In fact, JS throws an exception when doing:

```
...a = 4;
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Rest parameter may not have a default initializer
```

Why does this code output the modified array with the end `4`, instead of throwing an exception? How does this work exactly?

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Comment: *"how the `...a` get assigned to `4`"* It does not. What makes you think that? The output you are seeing is the result of evaluating `[0, ...a, 4]`. `[x, y, ...a ] = foo` means *"assign the first value of the iterable `foo` to `x`, the second one to `y` and the remaining ones as an array to `a`"*.

Comment: I see. Now makes sense why the output of `a` is `[2, 3, 4]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's not clear to me, though, how the `...a` get assigned to `4`.

It's not.

Lets split things up a little:

On the right hand side of the assignment you are using an array literal with a **spread element**. The value of `a` is "flattened" into the new array.

Thus, `[0, ...a, 4]` is is equivalent to `[0].concat(a, [4])`. The result is a new array.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];

console.log('spread element', [0, ...a, 4]);
console.log('concat', [0].concat(a, [4]));
```

On the left hand side you are using array destructuring with a **rest element**. `[x, y, ...a ]` means

- assign the first value of the iterable to `x`
- assign the second value of the iterable to `y`
- assign the remaining values of the iterable as an array to `a`

These two are equivalent:

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4];
var [x, y, ...z] = a;
console.log('destructuring', x, y, z);

var x = a[0];
var y = a[1];
var z = a.slice(2);
console.log('manual + slice', x, y, z);
```

---

Of course combining these two is perfectly fine. In an assignment, the left hand side doesn't care what how the right hand side is computed and vice versa.

What's confusing about your example is that you are using `a` again in the destructuring assignment, but that's the same as overriding the value of `a` with a new value. However the end result is

- `[0, ...a, 4]` results in `[0,1,2,3,4]` therefor
- `x` has value `0`
- `y` has value `1`
- `a` has value `[2,3,4]`

---

> In fact, JS throws an exception when doing: `...a = 4;`

The error message you are getting is strange. It should really be just a syntax error.

`...` by itself doesn't mean anything. It's not an operator, it's a punctuator (like `;` or `,`) that has a different meaning depending on the context it is used (and allowed).

See also [What is SpreadElement in ECMAScript documentation? Is it the same as Spread operator at MDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Answer (score 4):

It is executed like following

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
[x, y, ...a ] = [0, ...a, 4];
[x, y, ...a ] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
```

which means first value in RHS array is assigned to `x`, second value in RHS array is assigned to `y` and the remaining values are assigned to `a`.

Hence, value of `x` is `0`, `y` is `1` and `a` is `[2, 3, 4]`

Answer (score 3):

`...a` is either equal to `.slice(start, end)` (left, destructuring) or to `.concat(a)` (right, spreading):

```
 [0, ...a, 4]
```

is equal to:

```
[0].concat(a).concat([4]) // [0,1,2,3,4]
```

Whereas:

```
[x, y, ...a] = array
```

Is equal to:

```
x = array[0];
y = array[1];
a = array.slice(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, spread ie [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in LHS acts as gatherer whereas on the RHS it acts as spread/rest. IE you are assigning value to variable `a` when it is on LHS.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];

[x, y, ...a ] = [0, ...a, 4];

console.log(a)
```

Let's go step by step:

Let's start with RHS. Doing `[0, ...a, 4]` will generate `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. See for yourself:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];

console.log([0, ...a, 4]);
```

Now, the `LHS` is the side where assignment is taking place. On RHS, imagine any variable with spread operator as an `array` ready to be assigned new values.

So, we are trying to assign `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` to a variable `x`, then to `y` and the rest to array `a` (**in that order**). So, array `a` will have whatever will be left after first two assignments (ie `2, 3, 4`).

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];

// a will get overwritten
[x, y, ...a ] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
// same as [x, y, ...a ] = [0, ...a, 4];

console.log(a);
```

Finally, coming to your last question: "It's not clear to me, though, how the ...a get assigned to 4? "

Answer: It is **not**. But if you do something like `[...a] = [4]`, it will result in an array named `a` containing `[4]`.

You can read more about spread syntax [here (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [here (YDKJS)](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md).